# SharePoint QueryText

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, people-search

I have a question about SharePoint query text searching.

For example, if you were to enter inside the Query Text of the Query builder for People search Core Results it provides you the specific text matched but not others.

Here is an example:

With the Result Source Local People Results(System)

An example list of existing People : **Tester**, **Tester2** ,**Tester3**, **Sps Farm**

Query Text: **Tester**

It returns only **Tester** under **RelevantResults**.

However when you type Tester within the SearchBox in the SearchCenter it gives you **Tester**, **Tester2**, **Tester3**.

Does this mean that **Tester2** and **Tester3** come from a different KnownTableTypes?
Or is there something special with the Search Box Query appending to the entire Query?

Thanks for Reading.

I've found out that this scenario is the same for Search Results Web Part & Content Search Web Part. (I had even tried setting the web part to have the same settings as the people Web part[Which also uses Search Results Web Part] in Search Center.)

1) Add web part
2) Configure to Local People Results Source
3) Add Search Box
4) Connect Search Box to the web part
5) Search

OR another example.
Delete the People Search results web part from Search Center.
Add a Search Results to the same web part zone-> configure everything like the People Search Results Web Part.

Comment: Might be an issue with 'stemming' (=logic to get the 'root' form of a word) . I believe there are extra options in the SearchBox webpart to enable/ disable stemming. So a (configurable) search behavior difference between the Query Builder and SearchBox webpart?

Comment: Well, actually I was asking this because I created a custom elevated search web part that allows searching of everything( even with no permissions). I am using a text box within the web part to pass the search text as the Query Text. As for the results sources I made it select-able. So i tried EnableStemming= true, KeywordInclusion.AnyKeyword and it still only returns Tester only when I search for Tester. In fact when i search as Test, searchcenter returns Tester. But in my web part it returns no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel stupid now... after doing a comparison of both the People Search Web Part and Normal Search Web Part, the deciding factor was the code

```
EnablePhonetic = true;
```

Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the phonetic forms of the query terms are used to find matches.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.search.query.query.enablephonetic.aspx

After adding this, it shows all the users with names similar to the searched text.

As for the Test giving Tester.
It is

`EnableNickNames = true;`

Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the exact terms in the search query are used to find matches, or if nicknames are used as well.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.enablenicknames.aspx